# Is there a name for this type of inverse?

Tags: inverse

I have a function $f : A \to B$ and an inverse $f^{-1} : B \to A$, and the only property of the inverse is that $(f \circ f^{-1} \circ f)(x) = f(x)$.  In particular, it is not necessarily true that $(f^{-1} \circ f)(x) = x$.  I normally associate this property with inverses, so what should I call $f^{-1}$?

Comment: Are you trying to say that $f^{-1}$ is a right-inverse, but not a left-inverse?

Comment: It certainly appears that that is the [case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#Properties) for a bit more reading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such things come up in the theory of von Neumann regular rings. The object is sometimes called a pseudoinverse, but several different items are called by that name. It is called a pseudoinverse in the theory of [regular semigroups.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_semigroup)